# BIRT RPT design Cascading parameters report page is not opening

Tags: eclipse, birt

java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.EditorInputPropertyTester.test(EditorInputPropertyTester.java:44)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.Property.test(Property.java:58)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:99)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateOr(CompositeExpression.java:68)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.OrExpression.evaluate(OrExpression.java:21)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.ReferenceExpression.evaluate(ReferenceExpression.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:137)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:131)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.deactivate(EclipseContext.java:650)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.clearContext(PartRenderingEngine.java:970)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:954)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeRemoveGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$3(PartRenderingEngine.java:862)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$8.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:857)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.removeGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:841)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.hardClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1924)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyClose(WorkbenchWindow.java:1547)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.access$15(WorkbenchWindow.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$10.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1579)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:1576)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$14.run(Workbench.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$21(Workbench.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$19.run(Workbench.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.close(Workbench.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.restart(Workbench.java:2677)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.RestartWorkbenchHandler.execute(RestartWorkbenchHandler.java:32)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)